# Python how to standardise your dates to a particular datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My data might be of different date formats (dd-mm-yyyy hh mm, yyyy-mm-dd hh mm etc) and is in string format I want to push standardized data into my database. Also I want to convert into DateTime instead of string to use it in other date-related functions. How can  I do it? I tried pd.Datetime() and inserted the required format (the one I want to standardized to) but I'm getting this error :

> ValueError: time data '2015-05-04 09:15:00' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M' (match).

I have used flask to make an upload screen and using request.files to get the csv file in my python

[image: Here's how my date column looks after importing it from csv]

[image: Here's how it looks on excel (part1)]

[image: Here's how it looks on excel (part2)]
Please help me with it Thanks

Comment: there is no way to "standardise" e.g. if the month comes first or not in a date/time format. You'll have to *define* it or *guess* it from the context (e.g. data from a source in the US is likely gonna have month first, not day first as data from Germany could have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my data was being imported from an excel, I used the month,day and year feature of excel and then used  pd.to_datetime with month = column where the month is ( and so on for day and year).

`data_xls['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(data_xls[['Year','Month','Day','Hour','Minute']])`

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `infer_datetime_format` parameter in [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to quickly get around most formatting issues. Make sure you validate the output:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

For example, looking at different formats with the following test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-10-25','24-10-2020','2020-10-26 10:00:05']})
                  date
0           2020-10-25
1           24-10-2020
2  2020-10-26 10:00:05
```

Using:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Outputs:

```
                date
0 2020-10-25 00:00:00
1 2020-10-24 00:00:00
2 2020-10-26 10:00:05
```

Comment: I tried it but it resulted in some data errors for eg ( in yyyy-mm-dd ) 2015-8 (aug) - 12 was misinterpreted as 2015-12-8. I can't allow that

Comment: You can use `dayfirst` parameter, but without previous knowledge it'd be impossible to know if 2015-8-12 is referred as Aug 12, and perhaps another row 2015-8-12 refers to Dec 8. I suggest creating an extra column to flag which cases are flipped and treat them separetely. Let alone fixing the data input to start with.

Comment: I tried it but it resulted in some data errors for eg ( in yyyy-mm-dd ) 2015-8 (aug) - 12 was misinterpreted as 2015-12-8. I can't allow that.

for eg 

`df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-08-25','2020-08-12','12-10-2020 10:00:05']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)`

 date
0 2020-08-25 00:00:00
1 2020-08-12 00:00:00
2 2020-12-10 10:00:05


Like the last one should have been 12th October

Comment: Hey, My file name has a fixed format. Can I extract the month range from that ( say 1-4) and somehow check if all my dates are within this range after the conversion? That would solve the problem!

Comment: @CeliusStingher If you have mixed formats of datetime represented as string in one column, I think you *do not* want to set infer_datetime_format=True - this would assume all strings are formatted equally.

Comment: I don't. I have updated the main query please check it once and thanks for being such a good and an active help